# How to use jQuery in Meteor 1.0

Tags: jquery, meteor

I am trying to use jquery like this in meteor.js app.

JS:

```
    if (Meteor.isClient) {      
    Meteor.startup(function() {
            $( "button" ).click(function() {
              $( "p" ).toggle();
            });
          });
...
```

Or without meteor.startup function. Neither works.

HTML:

```
<button>Click</button>
<p>Can you see me?</p>
```

I get no errors and nothing happens when I click the button.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You shouldn't use jQuery for simple event handling like this, use Meteor templates event maps instead :

HTML :

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  <button type="button">Click me !</button>
  <p>Can you see me ?</p>
</template>
```

JS :

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  "click button":function(event, template){
    template.$("p").toggle();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, why my example jquery isn't working? It should, right?

Comment: Meteor takes full control over DOM management (that's why it's so easy to deal with in the first place, right ?) and cannot ensure that events you set using jQuery will be preserved on template re-rendering, so I assume that's why your code is failing, anyway stick to using Meteor templates stuff to avoid pitfalls.

Comment: I think but I'm not sure it doesn't work because on startup there are no DOM elements yet, it will probably work with .rendered event

Answer (score 7):

use `meteor list` to see if jquery package has included.
if not, use `meteor add jquery` to add the package

Comment: According to Meteor Docs and Athmosphere https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/jquery Jquery should be installed automatically. However I cannot see it listed. I installed it and now jquery works. The docs are pretty misleading.

Comment: Yeah, it appears jquery is "just there" even without an explicit package install.

Comment: @Bird Eggegg : `meteor list` lists the packages that you have explicitly added to your project (+ if you have a fresh meteor project, you will find 3 packages listed there autopublish, insecure, meteor-platform). If you want to see all the packages that come with meteor core you can look inside your project folder, inside the `.meteor` folder, in the `versions` file...

Answer (score 3):

on startup, your HTML is not likely to be rendered.  you want to do that on your templated.rendered event.

But, like others said, you don't want to do it that way anyways.

Comment: This is a correct answer here, but I'm noting although somewhat obviously calling $ in the isClient code and not isServer block is important to remember. It's included in Meteor 1.0 by default and doesn't show up in meteor list. Just try it but in client should work unless your accessing template dependencies so at least $("body") should work in isClient.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the standard jQuery DOM ready function before you write your application code as follows...

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    $(function() {
        // your jQuery code here...
    });
}
```