# Why does the div not hide when clicking outside of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, meteor

I am trying to make the div hide but it does not. [Here](http://meteorpad.com/pad/nHBXHriAt44LeRWqp/click%20outside) is a meteor pad showing the problem.

How can it be made to hide after clicking outside of it.

Here is the code if the meteor pad does not load

JS

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.hello.events({
    'click #loginbntstoggle' : function(e){
        if(document.getElementById("textoneandtwo").style.display=="none"){
            document.getElementById("logitextoneandtwonbnts").style.display = "block";
        }else{
            document.getElementById("textoneandtwo").style.display = "none";
        }
    },

  'click body' : function(e){
    if(e.target.className !== "textoneandtwo")
    {
      document.getElementById("textoneandtwo").style.display = "none";
    }
  }
});
}
```

HTML

```
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">

<button id="onoroff"
        class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
  <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
</button>

<div id="textoneandtwo" style="display: none;">
    <form action="#">
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample3" />
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Text...</label>
        </div>

        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample3" />
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Text...</label>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

</template>
```

Comment: That link won't load here.

Comment: sorry meteor pad is having issues i will add the code the the question

Comment: @Cyrbil <div id="textoneandtwo" style="display: none;">

Answer (score 0):

I think below code can help you. Just put your div element id in below code:

```
function bodyClickHandller(evt){
    if(!($.contains(divElement, evt.target)) || (divElement == evt.target))){
        $(divElement).hide();
    }
}
$("body").off("click").on("click", bodyClickHandller);
var divElement = document.getElementById("div_element_id");
```

Please let me know if you will face any issue.

Comment: I have edited the [meteor pad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/nHBXHriAt44LeRWqp/click%20outside) to show the error returned by your code. The error is Unexpected token ( on right after $

Comment: yes i know meteor and jquery are weird together take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116880/how-to-use-jquery-in-meteor-1-0)