# Button in wrong place in meteor app

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I made a little app and my button shows only on one place. It's all working but on wrong place. See pictures. I'll leave my [GitHub repo link](https://github.com/dale032/predlozi-GIT.git). Sorry most of stuff is on Cyrillic but code is, of course, on English Latin.

[Here is a video of my problem (22 sec)](https://youtu.be/ud23v6Oo9xY)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You're problem is with `id`. HTML `id`s are unique, so when you do `document.getElementById('skocko')`, you only get back the first element with that id.

Instead, give the button a class of `skocko`, and access it like this:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
    "click .glasaj":function(event, template){
      template.$(".skocko").toggle();
    }
}
```

This will select the element with class `skocko` in the current template.

SRC: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27116956/2317712

Comment: That makes sense, how to fix that than? I cant do it with class?

Comment: 'document.getElementsByClassName(skočkobrat)' tried this but it does not work

Comment: Updated solution. I haven't used meteor too much, so see if that works.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('skocko')` doesn't work because `getElementsByClassName` gives you an array of all elements with `class="skocko"`.

Comment: Still not showing, class is problem..

Comment: Did you update the skocko HTML template to have `class="skocko"`? Try typing `document.getElementsByClassName('skocko')` in the browser console (Ctrl+Shift+J in Chrome, F12 and select console in Firefox) and see if it found it.

Answer (score 0):

check div positioning   [How to position one element relative to another with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158070/how-to-position-one-element-relative-to-another-with-jquery)     so its position can be relative to button clicked, or assign unique skocko id for every skocko..

Comment: I think it is not possible to assign unique ID for every skocko, it's Meteor, there will be a lot staff in my MongoDB and a lot of stuff in one collection. Is it possible to make code that will generete ID for every skocko and change code to show popup next to button user clicked? I think this is much harder, can I just make somehow only one div and make it popup next to cursor when clicking specific buttons??? Thanks

Comment: yes, just in click event set position to your skocko

Comment: Can you be a little more specific ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this in your script glasaj.js

```
     if (Meteor.isClient) {
Template.glasajDugme.events({
      'click .glasaj': function(){        
          var g = Meteor.user().profile.неискоришћениГласови;
          if (g < 1) {


              var pos = $(this).position();
              // .outerWidth() takes into account border and padding.
              var width = $(this).outerWidth();

              //show the menu directly over the placeholder
              $("#skocko").css({
                  position: "absolute",
                  top: pos.top + "px",
                  left: (pos.left + width) + "px"
              }).show();

              document.getElementById('skocko').style.display = "inline-flex";
           // return "disabled" ;
          } 
          else {
            Predlozi.update(this._id, {$inc: {Број_Гласова: 1}}
            );
            Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {$inc: {"profile.неискоришћениГласови": -1}}
            );              
          };
      }      
 });
sakrijskocka = function(){
     document.getElementById('skocko').style.display = "none";
   }; 

 };
```

Comment: This is complex, I will just make div me showed up whenever some fild in MongoDB is specific value